# Active Admin and Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, activeadmin

I'm currently using Active Admin for the admin side of my Rails app. I'm also using Mongoid to connect to the MongoDB.

In this issue, I have teams and players. Players are assigned to a team. In my active admin form, i have:

```
f.input :team_id, :as => :select, :collection => Team.all,:member_label => (:name), :member_value => :id
```

The problem is the id for the team object is a BSON::Object(id) rather than just an id. Active Admin doesn't save the id as an object id. This is fine as long as I can pull out the players by team.

I'm trying to do

```
players = Player.where(:team_id => @team.id.to_s)
```

and that doesn't work.

If teamA.id = BSON::Object("asdf1234")
and playerA.team_id = "asdf1234"

I need to issue the mongoid query somehow to pull out players that have team_id="asdf1234"

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What does generated query look like (in develoment.log)?

Answer (score 1):

I think ActiveAdmin only works with ActiveRecord, if you want to use Mongoid, use this instead: 
https://github.com/elia/activeadmin-mongoid

Answer (score 0):

Before using activeadmin-mongoid, you need to translate all your primary/foreign keys to use BSON::ObjectIds rather than plain numbers which won't work.
I use mongify for this.
http://mongify.com/